# Tmux Terminfo problem with Zsh key bindings

Tags: debian, terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Zsh in Emacs edit mode comes with the default key binding <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete a word on the right side of the cursor and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to delete a word on the left side. I would like to add the latter function to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> additionally.

I tried to use the `terminfo` database to set the escape sequence for the key combination for every `$TERM` correctly. In `man terminfo` I read about `kDC3` being the Capname which I probably need to use for <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

I added the following line to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -e `tput kDC3` kill-word
```

This works nicely when I connect to my machine directly through SSH (`$TERM` is `xterm`). But when I start Zsh inside a Tmux-session (`$TERM` is `screen`) I get the following error message:

```
tput: unknown terminfo capability 'kDC3'
```

Could that really mean that it's impossible to bind anything to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> in Tmux? Or am I just doing something wrong? Maybe `kDC3` is not the correct sequence?

I'm running Debian Wheezy Beta 4 x86_64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that your *terminfo* entry for `screen` does not define a `kDC3` capability; this is probably typical. You can either add this capability to your own custom `screen` entry, or you can “hard code” the sequences in your `bindkey` commands.

---

Adding the capabilities may help other programs know about the keys, but it decentralizes your configuration (it would be easy to forget about this customization when you manually replicate your configuration to a new machine or user account). You can extract the appropriate entries with `infocmp` and build a new entry with `tic`:

```
{ infocmp -xT screen ; infocmp -x1T xterm | grep -E '^\tkDC[3-8]?=' ; } >/tmp/s
tic -x /tmp/s
```

If you run *tic* as a user that has write access to your terminfo directory (e.g. `/usr/share/terminfo`), then the new entry will be placed there (probably overwriting the original entry); otherwise, it will be placed under `~/.terminfo` (or TERMINFO, if you have that environment variable set).

For completeness, you may want to use `(UP|DN|RIT|LFT|PRV|NXT|HOM|END|IC|DC)` instead of `DC` in the *grep* pattern to capture the modified versions of Up, Down, Right, Left, PageUp, PageDown, Home, End, Insert, and Delete.

---

If you dislike the configuration decentralization caused by customizing your terminfo entry, then you can “hard code” the value instead. To make it a bit better, you can check for `kDC3` first:

```
bindkey -e ${$(tput kDC3 2>/dev/null):-'\e[3;3~'} kill-word
```

To restrict this “hard coding” to just `screen`-based TERM values:

```
altdel=$(tput kDC3 2>/dev/null)
[[ -z $altdel && $TERM == screen(|-*) ]] && altdel='\e[3;3~'
[[ -n $altdel ]] && bindkey -e $altdel kill-word
unset altdel
```

This will work as long as your terminal emulator (stack) ends up generating the *xterm*-style sequence for the modified key.

---

Once to have a binding, you will still need to turn on the `xterm-keys` option in *tmux* so that it will generate the *xterm*-style sequences for keys passed into its panes. E.g. in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -wg xterm-keys on
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a plausible reason for xterm-keys not being enabled by default and the capability not being setup by default?

Comment: I think they are related. The `screen` terminfo entry documents the codes the *screen* program understands and generates; I do not think that *screen* understands, nor generates the *xterm*-style codes (though it does appear to pass them through), so they are not part of the `screen` terminfo entry. The `xterm-keys` option represents an **extension** to the basic `screen` capabilities (that *tmux* advertises by using `TERM=screen`), so it is off-by-default (maybe it could be on-by-default when (e.g.) `TERM=tmux`, if *tmux* ever decides to fork its own terminfo entry).

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- ncurses supports extended ([user-definable](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S)) terminal capabilities.
- **`kDC3`** is an *extended* terminal capability.
- None of `tmux`, `zsh` or `emacs` know anything at *all* about `kDC3`.
- although `tmux` has `kDC3` in a *table*, it does not call [`use_extended_names`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_extend.3x.html) to enable the feature.
- ncurses `tput` would know about `kDC3`, *if* it is defined in the current terminal description.

The `screen` program (which `tmux` imitates) also knows nothing about `kDC3`.  It is a *termcap* application, and (for itself) pays attention only to 2-character names.  However, `screen` has a feature which addresses the question directly: in the manual ([16.1 Choosing the termcap entry for a window](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Termcap)) it tells how it chooses the setting for `TERM` *inside* the screen session:

> When `screen` tries to figure out a terminal name for itself, it first looks for an entry named `screen.`*term*, where *term* is the contents of your `$TERM` variable. If no such entry exists, screen tries **`screen`** (or **`screen-w`**, if the terminal is wide (132 cols or more)). If even this entry cannot be found, **`vt100`** is used as a substitute.
>
> The idea is that if you have a terminal which doesn't support an important feature (e.g. delete char or clear to EOS) you can build a new termcap/terminfo entry for screen (named **`screen.dumbterm`**) in which this capability has been disabled. If this entry is installed on your machines you are able to do a rlogin and still keep the correct termcap/terminfo entry. The terminal name is put in the `$TERM` variable of all new windows. screen also sets the `$TERMCAP` variable reflecting the capabilities of the virtual terminal emulated. Furthermore, the variable `$WINDOW` is set to the window number of each window.

ncurses' terminal database exploits this feature to provide the most common variants of `screen` with [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-new) and other terminals which are similar but have *different* function keys, such as [konsole](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_konsole), [vte](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_vte) (e.g., gnome-terminal), [rxvt](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_rxvt).  Except for `rxvt`, the others still set `TERM` to `xterm`.

In a default configuration, you may not have those terminal descriptions available (and `screen` would blithely continue to set `TERM=screen` and provoke users into bug reports much like this question). Debian, for instance, in its [*ncurses-base*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses-base) terminfo package provides only a minimal set of terminal descriptions.  You would have to install [`ncurses-term`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses-term) to get the complete terminal database.

The terminal description for `screen`, of course, does not describe any extended function keys.  It does include these extended capabilities, by the way:

```
AX, G0, E0=\E(B, S0=\E(%p1%c,
```

but none of these applications (except `tput`) does anything with them.

`tmux` complicates this by not completely matching the behavior of `screen`: it does not check for the alternate names which ncurses provides.  Without explaining why, its [manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) says

> The `TERM` environment variable must be set to `“screen”` for all programs running inside `tmux`. New windows will automatically have `“TERM=screen”` added to their environment, but care must be taken not to reset this in shell start-up files.

The likely reason is that the developer did not want to guarantee the behavior (for screen updates) of terminal capabilities not found in `screen`.  Function keys are a different matter.  You can modify the terminal description as suggested, though that has proven to be moe of a problem than a solution:

- [My terminal is not recognized](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#unknown_term)
- [How do I set up a private terminfo database?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#home_terminfo)

The [suggested script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57841/105132), by the way, does not appear to work.  Showing a corrected script would be pointless, given all of the background for this problem.  Rather than piecemeal tweaks to the terminal database, I would be inclined to have a case statement in the shell initialization that checked for `TERM` set to `screen`, and check if there is a better alternative already in the terminal database.  Doing that correctly is made more complicated by developers' refusal to set `TERM` according to their terminal's capabilities, but you can get most of the way there by looking at the `COLORTERM` environment variable.

For your amusement:

- [Where is COLORTERM set?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.slackware/3725)
- [Support custom TERM and COLORTERM env vars](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/794561)
- [Change environment variable (TERM)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446076/change-environment-variable-term)
- [Export enviromental variable which would indicate that we are in KMSCON #60](https://github.com/dvdhrm/kmscon/issues/60)
- [How can I detect Gnome Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-detect-gnome-terminal)
- [RoxTerm #38 [PATCH] Make overriding TERM environment varible posible](https://sourceforge.net/p/roxterm/bugs/38/)
- [Fedora: Features/256 Color Terminals](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals)

Answer (score 0):

From what ive seen of the internals of tmux it doesnt seem to pay much attention to terminfo settings and the like. For example if you turn on xterm mode:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

the actual escape sequences corresponding to various keys are hardcoded into the program and are probably different from what `infocmp xterm` would tell you.

On top of this tmux ignores everything above `F20` because it only has a certain set of keys that it will recognise hardcoded in. So something like this

```
set-option -g terminal-overrides "screen:kf34=\033[21;5~"
```

or

```
tmux bind-key -t emacs-copy F34 page-up
```

isnt going to accomplish anything, no matter what xterm or tput is spitting out. At least thats the way it seems to be at present.

I'm not sure if the same issue is effecting something like `kDC3` but it seems quite possible.